# Changing branches in Perforce

Tags: version-control, branch, perforce

The client has asked me to submit changes into a different, pre-existing branch in their Perforce repo, but I'm having a tough time figuring out the process for that.

What's the Perforce equivalent of `git checkout other-branch`? Search engines are failing me; possibly because I'm using Git terminology and/or concepts that don't actually exist in p4.

Once I have the other branch "checked out" or whatever the correct p4 terminology is, can I just create and submit my changesets in the normal way?

Are there any caveats to doing this in the CLI versus p4v? I've mostly been using the latter because I'm a n00b.

Comment: Is the client expecting you to create the other branch? Or have they already done that for you? If they have created the other branch, you can just checkout the files and submit the changelists in the normal way.

Comment: Yes, the other branch already exists, or so I've been told. Edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Branch specs in Perforce are just different paths.  If you have something like

```
//depot/product/main/...
```

in your p4 client spec, you'd change it to

```
//depot/product/branch/...
```

to get the branch, and use p4 sync to get the files and p4 add/edit/delete/submit as per usual to make changes.  You'd merge changes between branches using p4 integrate.

See the [Perforce docs](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Integrating_files_into_codelines.html) for more info.

Comment: Is it possible that the branch paths might look different, like be in a subdirectory of the product directory? I can see `//[company]/[product]/main/` (where I've been working so far), but I don't see anything else that looks like the branch they want me working in under `//[company]/[product]/` - but I do under `//[company]/[product]/release/`.

Comment: Make sure that your workspace view mapping includes the branch. Your view of the repository is automatically narrowed to include only those files that are mentioned by your view.

Comment: Are `//[company]/[product]/main/` and `//[company]/[product]/release/[branch-name]/` "views" in the context you're using? If I can see those, doesn't it mean that my workspace view mapping includes the branch?

Answer (score 0):

`p4 workspace` is the command you want. If you're using p4v you can just add that branch to a new workspace.

You may also find this handy dandy comparison chart useful. http://www.perforce.com/sites/default/files/command-comparison.pdf

Or this cheat sheet: https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/attachment/91198/cheat_sheet.pdf